# Computed Value cant be seen maybe because of null

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My Code here is to Know the status of my inventory on a certain range of date , but i'm having a problem when it comes to stock it returns no value.

I have no values in Pullover still it should compute for the stock = DELIVERED - (SOLD + PULLOVER)
Here is the code.

```
Select A.prod_name As Product, A.prod_totalPrice As Price, A.prod_category As Category, A.prod_ExpDate As Expiration,
ifnull((Select SUM(itp_needQty) from tbl_itmonpur Where itp_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name)and itp_statusDelv = 'DELIVERED' and itp_date Between "10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014"),0) As Delivered, 
ifnull((Select SUM(sales_qty) from tbl_sales Where sales_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name)AND sales_date between"10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014" ),0) As Sold, 
ifnull((Select SUM(po_qty) from tbl_PullOver Where po_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name) AND po_date between "10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014" ),0) As PullOut, 
ifnull((Select SUM(itp_needQty) from tbl_itmonpur Where itp_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name)and itp_statusDelv = 'DELIVERED' and itp_date Between "10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014") - ((Select SUM(sales_qty) from tbl_sales Where sales_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name)AND sales_date between "10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014" ) + (Select SUM(po_qty) from tbl_PullOver Where po_prodID = (Select prod_id from tbl_prod where prod_name = A.prod_name) AND po_date between "10/06/2014" and "10/06/2014")), 0) As Stock,
S.supp_name As Supplier 
From tbl_prod As A 
Inner Join tbl_supp As S 
On A.prod_suppID = S.supp_id 
Group By Product;
```

I'm just a student please be easy on me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running each of the subqueries independently and seeing what results you get from them?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the [`coalesce()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to deal with that kind of situations:

> - **`coalesce(value, ...)`**
>
>   Returns the first non-`NULL` value in the list, or `NULL` if there are no non-`NULL` values.

*Example:*

```sql
select coalesce(1, 2, 3);           -- Will return 1
select coalesce(null, 2, 3);        -- Will return 2
select coalesce(1, null, 3);        -- Will return 1
select coalesce(null, null, null);  -- Will return null
```